# servletConfig.getInitParameterNames() is not working

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, web.xml, servletconfig

I need to show two URLs into a JSP, but I want to pass some init parameters to the JSP page for doing this.

So, this is my web.xml :

```
<web-app ... >
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>index1</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/index.jsp</jsp-file>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>p1</param-name>
        <param-value>http://www.google.com</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>p2</param-name>
        <param-value>/pagina2.jsp</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>index1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In the index.jsp, I wrote the following code:

```
<%
    // This is only a test code. Obviously, it doesn't show the URLs
      java.util.Enumeration e = getServletConfig().getInitParameterNames();
      while( e.hasMoreElements() ) {
          out.println( e.nextElement() + "<br>");
      }
    %>
```

But when I run the jsp, this show some initParameters that I don't need. By example:

  `logVerbosityLevel

  httpMethods

  keepgenerated

  p2     ----------- > This is the parameter that I need


  xpoweredBy

  p1     ----------- > This is other parameter that I need

  system-jar-includes

  com.sun.appserv.jsp.classpath`

My questions is:
Why the JSP file are using all this parameters?
Note: I'm using Glassfish.

Comment: Well now I've put all code into a Servlet. And it works now. But What does the other parameters mean? (logVerbosityLevel, httpMethods ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are the initialization parameters of the container-builtin `JspServlet` class who's responsible for serving JSP files. In case of Glassfish, you can find it in `config/default-web.xml` file of the domain. It's the servlet entry of `org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet` (note, you should not modify it unless you really understand what you're doing).

Comment: Thanks a lot, @BalusC. Well, I'm still learning Jsp 1.2, before seeing Jps 2.0 new features. I'll try to write what you said. Thanks again.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I tried the first way: 
<a href="${initParam.p1}">w</a>
But it generates a URL like that: <a href="http://localhost:port/myProject">w</a>

But I suppose I did something wrong.

Comment: D'oh, sorry I mixed it up. In spite of the name `${initParam}`, it actually refers `<context-param>` entires of `web.xml`. It's not possible to access JSP servlet init params in EL. I'll edit the answer to remove the incorrect information.